# Send ImageUri from the gallery using navController in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, uri, gallery

I am creating an app in Android Studio with Jetpack Compose. In a main screen, I have a button, that when it is clicked, it opens the gallery through registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()), then when the image is picked, it navigates to another screen where the image is displayed, and then analysed with MlKit vision. This is the mainActivity

```
private val selectMedia = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()){ uri ->
        if (uri != null){
            val encodedUri = Uri.encode(
                uri
                    .toString()
                    .replace('%', '|')
            )
        }
    }


    @ExperimentalPermissionsApi
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @ExperimentalCoilApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            AppNavigation(navController = navController, selectMedia, encodedUri)
        }
```

This is the mainScreen that has a button, that when is clicked it launches the gallery

```
 Modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .clickable {
                                selectMedia.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly))
                            }, contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                        Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
                            val gallery =
                                painterResource(id = R.drawable.icons8_im_genes_de_carpetas_32__1_)
                            Image(
                                painter = gallery,
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(36.dp, 36.dp)
                            )
                            Text(text = "Imágenes", fontFamily = Inter, fontSize = 12.sp)
                        }
                    }
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = selectMedia){
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(AppScreens.SecondScreenImage.route + "/{$encodedUri}")
                    }
```

I want to pass the uri to this secondScreen

```
fun secondScreen(navController: NavHostController, textUri : String?){

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    val context = LocalContext.current

    val imageUri = textUri?.toUri()

    val textChanged = mutableStateOf("")
    val recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS)

    val image = InputImage.fromFilePath(context, imageUri!!)
    recognizer.process(image)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            textChanged.value = it.text
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("TEXT_REC", it.message.toString())
        }
```

I wanted to now, how can I from the MainActivity (where the constant to open the gallery is located), pass the uri when the image is chosen, and then send that uri to the other screen (it is called SecondScreen) with this navigation logic

```
fun AppNavigation(navController : NavHostController, viewModel: MainViewModel){
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = AppScreens.SplashScreen.route){
        composable(route = AppScreens.SplashScreen.route){
            splashScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(route = AppScreens.FirstScreen.route){
            firstScreen(navController, viewModel)
        }
        composable(route = AppScreens.Camera.route){
            CameraCapture(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route = AppScreens.SecondScreenImage.route + "/{textUri}", arguments = listOf(navArgument("textUri"){
            this.type = NavType.StringType
        })){
            secondScreen(navController = navController, it.arguments?.getString("textUri"))
        }
        composable(route = AppScreens.SecondScreenText.route + "/{text}", arguments = listOf(navArgument("text"){
            this.type = NavType.StringType
        })){
            secondScreenText(navController = navController, it.arguments?.getString("text"))
        }
    }
}
```